# Cabal configure in a sandbox complains "At least the following dependencies are missing" on installed packages

Tags: haskell, cabal

I have a project, it's inside a sandbox, I introduced a test-suite in my cabal file and it `build-depends` on `hunit ==1.2.*`. The problem is when I try to configure:

> **$ cabal configure --enable-tests**
>   Resolving dependencies...
>   Configuring MyProject-0.1.0.0...
>   cabal: At least the following dependencies are missing:
>   hunit ==1.2.*

A few more attempts to get it to come around:

> **$ cabal install --dependencies-only**
>   Resolving dependencies...
>   All the requested packages are already installed:
>   Use --reinstall if you want to reinstall anyway.

&

> **$ cabal install hunit**
>   Resolving dependencies...
>   All the requested packages are already installed:
>   HUnit-1.2.5.2
>   Use --reinstall if you want to reinstall anyway.

&

> **$ cabal install --enable-tests**
>   Resolving dependencies...
>   cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
>   trying: MyProject-0.1.0.0 (user goal)
>   rejecting: MyProject-0.1.0.0:!test (global constraint requires opposite flag
>   selection)
>   trying: MyProject-0.1.0.0:*test
>   next goal: hunit (dependency of MyProject-0.1.0.0:*test)
>   fail (unknown package: hunit)
>   Dependency tree exhaustively searched.

`--reinstall`ing did nothing.
I even played with the `--user` and `--global` flags, even tho I'm using `cabal` and not `runhaskell`, it doesn't help it.
I also tried to `delete` & re-`init` the sandbox.
I tried just `delete`ing the sandbox too, and it still gave me the same error.
`ghc-pkg check` finds nothing wrong.

What could it be?
By the way a part of me is suspicious that cabal ignores that my project is in a sandbox, since it didn't bother to install some packages that were already on my machine; it does so on my Windows (this is on Ubuntu). Is it possible to get that checked?

Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
GHC version: 7.6.3
cabal-install version: 1.20.0.3
Cabal library version: 1.20.0.2

Also tried now with cabal-install 1.16.0.2 without success.

Comment: `cabal install --enable-tests`?

Comment: To expand on @MarkWhitfield 's comment, `cabal install` does a configure.  Pass it the configuration flags you need.

Comment: @MarkWhitfield @Carl Thank you. I've tried it and unfortunately it didn't work. For some reason `hunit` is an unknown package now..? I've updated the question with the details.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Package names are case sensitive in Cabal/Hackage, the correct package name is [HUnit](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HUnit).  Change the line in your cabal file containing:

```
hunit ==1.2.*
```

To

```
HUnit ==1.2.*
```

Comment: I just died laughing. Thank you so much! it's working perfectly.