# Why can't I cabal install --only-dependencies with mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, haskell, cabal

I have gone through the following steps:

```
$ mkdir mongoEg
$ cd mongoEg
$ cabal init
 ...
```

Configured to run as an executable. I add `mongodb` to the `build-depends` list. I make a dummy `Main.hs` file and put a basic hello world in there.  I then do

```
$ cabal sandbox init
$ cabal install --only-dependencies
```

Which responds with:

```
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
trying: monogEg-0.1.0.0 (user goal)
next goal: mongodb (dependency of monogEg-0.1.0.0)
Dependency tree exhaustively searched.

Note: when using a sandbox, all packages are required to have consistent
dependencies. Try reinstalling/unregistering the offending packages or
recreating the sandbox.
```

I read up on other problems people are having, and remove `~/.ghc`, remove my `mongoEg` directory, and repeat to get the same results.  I try to run through the analogous steps at http://howistart.org/posts/haskell/1 and find that everything works just fine.

I then guess that something is wrong with the `mongodb` package itself.  I seem to be able to `cabal install mongodb` in a global environment and use it outside of a sandbox without any issue. So, why wont cabal sandboxes play with the mongodb package?

See this gist for details: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e5a548cf7d9ec59bea31

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking here

[Cabal configure in a sandbox complains "At least the following dependencies are missing" on installed packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25107967/cabal-configure-in-a-sandbox-complains-at-least-the-following-dependencies-are)

I saw that the answer states that package names are case sensitive.  So I tried changing `mongodb` to the way MongoDB spells it, namely `MongoDB`. This did not work, so I tried changing it to `mongoDB`, and finally there was joy.

So even though I can do `cabal install mongodb` I can't use that same spelling to install it from within a `.cabal` file, which is, obviously, completely stupid.  I'm sure I'll find the right place to channel my rage about this kind of flagrant violation of the [principle of least surprise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment), but for now I can say that to newcomers it is most needlessly confusing.

Comment: And this is why I absolutely hate QuickCheck for using capitals, same with mongoDB.